# Error (in GTK?) when trying to install EclipseXul plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, xul

When [installing EclipseXul plugin](http://eclipsexul.sourceforge.net/chapter-installation.html) on EclipsePHP, it says:

> Cannot complete the install because
>   one or more required items could not
>   be found.   Software currently
>   installed: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1288098146566 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php
>   1.0.0.1288098146566)   Missing requirement: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1288098146566 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php
>   1.0.0.1288098146566) requires 'SharedProfile_epp.package.php
>   [1.0.0.1288098145696]' but it could
>   not be found

Any idea what's wrong?

**--update**

When running from the terminal, I can see a message, when I open the updates windows:

> ** (Eclipse:3364): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion
>   `height >= -1' failed

Recently I have my whole home folder deleted by a script. Maybe there's something with this.. But I just downloaded a brand new Eclipse installation and put it in my /home/eclipse/ folder.

Comment: the output on the console is some error message from gtk, it's not related to your installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your current user doesn't have write permission on your eclipse installation, so eclipse creates share configuration to manage the installation and other configurations. But eclipse has several bugs related to share installation on 3.6.

Try to install your eclipse in a folder that has write permission, then install other plug-ins.

Comment: It's installed in my home folder (in Ubuntu). I also tried running with sudo, but the same message appears.

Comment: I tried installing Xul, it works well. So I think it's caused by your eclipse configuration, your eclipse probably can't install any plug-in. If your eclipse is a new fresh package downloaded from eclipse.org, and it lays in your home directory. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error in Win7 when I copied from the Eclipse .zip straight to Program Files.  Eclipse would run, but apparently didn't have write permissions.  Moving it somewhere else fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Users:

- Uncheck the Eclipse folder read only permission.
- Choose to run Eclipse as Administrator in Compatibility tab.