# Failed to install Android ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt

I'm trying to install the `ADT` to `Eclipse Indigo` (32 bit). It consistently fails with the following message:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

> Software currently installed: Shared
>   profile 1.0.0.1308118821836
>   (SharedProfile_epp.package.java
>   1.0.0.1308118821836)
>
> Missing requirement: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1308118821836 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java
>   1.0.0.1308118821836) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse
>   [1.0.0.20110607-2117]' but it could
>   not be found

I've tried reinstalling the ADT and the `Android SDK`, and Eclipse, without any luck. None of the other questions on this site seem relevant. I'm wondering if it's related to the migration of M2Eclipse from Sonotype to Eclipse, but I can't find anything.

EDIT:In order to explain why the answer accepted worked, I was installing on Windows 7 Home to an account that did have Admin permission and no password. However Win7 still prompts for the Admin password when you do something that needs Admin permission, even though the account has that permission and the password is empty. It seems that the ADT installation fails even under those circumstances. When I install to a non-Admin area it works.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try running Eclipse as Super/Admin User, or move Eclipse installation somewhere with write permissions.

This answer helped a lot: [Error (in GTK?) when trying to install EclipseXul plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025868/error-in-gtk-when-trying-to-install-eclipsexul-plugin)

Comment: Just allow write/modify for All Users, like i did on "C:\Program Files\eclipse" folder. Simple. No need to run as admin user.

Comment: on osx, moved the eclipse from the apps to my home folder and it worked. very weird eclipse behavior indeed.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. Lesson learned, from now on check StackOverflow first before following advice of some random forum thread!

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is an Eclipse bug, fixed in the next release.  The central shared install needn't be writable to run eclipse (it should just install additional plugins into the user's cascaded configuration).  See also:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350645

Answer (score 1):

In linux, making the whole eclipse directory writable to the world solves this problem. Assuming that the eclipse is installed in `/opt/eclipse`:

```
#chmod -R 777 /opt/eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error on Ubuntu 11.04 after having installed Eclipse 3.5 via the package manager, removed it, and then installed 3.7 manually.  It was a result of some leftover bits of the previous version.  Here's what I did to fix it, more or less: (NOTE: this will wipe your Eclipse configuration!).  If you use a nonstandard workspace location, adjust the path in the second line.

```
sudo apt-get purge eclipse-platform libecj-java eclipse libequinox-osgi-java
rm -rf ~/.eclipse ~/workspace/.metadata
```